# How to get all values with the same key in an immut. dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('course', u'2132'), ('course', u'2121'), 
('myc', u''), ('ok', u'Add to my plan')])
```

is the dict I get in my WSGI-Code written in Python.

Now I want to get all entries with the `course` key, but `args.get("course")` only returns the first value of `2132`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`getlist`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist) method, like this

```
immutable_dict_obj.getlist("course")
```

This will return a list of values corresponding to the key `course`.

Comment: @Saphire You mean, I have a typo or you had a typo?

Comment: I had a typo. I wrote `courses` as soon as I saw `getlist` :)