# Iterate over keys and all values in MultiDict

Tags: python, flask

I have a dictionary

```
params = ImmutableMultiDict([('dataStore', 'tardis'), ('symbol', '1'), ('symbol', '2')])
```

I want to be able to iterate through the dictionary and get a list of all the values and their keys. However, when I try to do it, it only gets the first symbol key value pair and ignores the other one.

```
for k in params:
    print(params.get(k))
```

Comment: Do you mean https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/master/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.ImmutableMultiDict?

Comment: What is `ImmutableMultiDict`? This is not a class in standard Python.

Comment: Its from Flask, The question stills stands if you were to use a regular dictionary

Comment: It doesn't stand if you were to use a regular dictionary, because if you're not using a `MultiDict` there *aren't* duplicate keys.

Comment: ok Fair enough then

Comment: You probably want to use `getlist`, not `get`.

Comment: even ```ImmutableMultiDict``` is in flask, you can still use ```iteritems()``` on dictionary.

Comment: @AkashPagar `iteritems` still only returns one pair per key.

Comment: I'm out of votes, but dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23323993/3001761

Comment: @AkashPagar although you could use [`.items`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/master/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.items) with the extra `multi` parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to iterate over all keys, including duplicates, right? Then you could use the [`items(multi=False)`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.items) method with `multi` set to `True`.

Documentation:

> #### items(*multi*=*False*)
>
> Return an iterator of `(key, value)` pairs.
>
> **Parameters**:   `multi` – If set to *True* the iterator returned will have a pair for each value of each key. Otherwise it will only contain
> pairs for the first value of each key.

If I misunderstood you and you want a list of all entries to a single key have a look at jonrsharpe's answer.

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: Updated the link, sorry, only just saw your comment.

Answer (score 5):

If you read the docs for [`MultiDict`](https://www.kite.com/python/docs/werkzeug.MultiDict), from which `ImmutableMultiDict` is derived, you can see:

> It behaves like a normal dict thus all dict functions will only return the first value when multiple values for one key are found.

However, the API includes an additional method, [`.getlist`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/master/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist), for this purpose. There's an example of its use in the docs, too:

> ```
> >>> d = MultiDict([('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c')])
> # ...
> >>> d.getlist('a')
> ['b', 'c']
> ```

Comment: This worked I can extract both items from the same key, thanks